# NPM downgrading not taking effect

Tags: npm

Currently on version 8.5.3 and trying to downgrade to v6. The output seems fine but the result is still 8.5.3 even after restarting shells/OS:

```
PS C:\Users\myUser> npm install -g npm@latest-6

removed 384 packages, changed 3 packages, and audited 54 packages in 8s

found 0 vulnerabilities
PS C:\Users\myUser> npm --version
8.5.3
```

Powershell is being run with administration privileges, due to some errors when running it without privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```sh
npm install -g npm@latest-6
```

Use this:

```sh
npm install -g npm@6.14.16
```

And after that reboot (restart) your computer

Answer (score 0):

for your version please use
**npm install -g npm@6.14.4**

for latest version please use
**npm install -g npm@latest**